# How to get a collection of values as an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I am creating a library that will be used as an API to work with a specific website. I have a list of states and cities with their corresponding IDs on the website.

The list of states and their list of cities must be accessible in design-mode (A developer should be able to access the list without compiling). I did this by creating a static class with static variables.

Here is how it looks.

```
    public class States
    {
       public static readonly States Arizona = new States(451, "Arizona", "lat", "lon");
       //many of these here

       public States(int key, string value, string lat, string lon, Cities cities)
       {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Name = value;
        this.Latitude = lat;
        this.Longitude = lon;
        this.Cities = cities;
       }
    }
    public class Cities
    {
       public static readonly Cities Phoenix = new States(1, States.GetById(451), "Phoenix", "lat", "lon");

       public Cities(int key, States state, string value, string lat, string lon)
       {  
        this.Key = key;
        this.Name = value;  
        this.State = state;
        this.Latitude = lat;
        this.Longitude = lon;
       }
    }
```

It will be used as: `var x = States.Arizona.Phoenix.Key;`

So. When getting a specific enum via States.GetById() - everything is fine. 
But.. how should I make the same thing for States.Cities? It definately should be a collection, but then the user (developer) will not have the ability to select a specific city without calling a "look up by name" function or something.

I *could* do a separate class for each state... But that just sounds like a really really wrong way to do it. 
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: _"without doing a"look up by name"-function"_ why can't you use a `Dictionary<string, Cities>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I guess the lack of Intellisense on the specific state / city names.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: As Patrick Hofman said, because of lack of Intellisense on that. The developer would need to look up the city himself beforehand.

Comment: So whenever a new city needs to be supported, you have to ship everybody a new API?  Why do they need to be available at design-time?  Are developers hard-coding the cities/states into their applications?

Comment: It's for an API for a marketplace. The list of states and cities is provided by the website itself serialized in a JSON string. 
So if something will change on their side, yes, that would require an update of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you need to have a separate class for each state, usually deriving a base class to get the standard methods, properties, etc.

The problem you face then is typically a code generation issue. You want to have a bunch of code, with as least as effort as possible. We generate a database model to c# code and we find XSLT useful for this. We have an XML file with all the values (extracted by another tool), and an XSLT that transforms that to classes.

Comment: I thought that I may be missing something, because such redundant code generation seemed too impractical to me. But it looks like you are right

Comment: If you want intellisense to work, it is the only option. If you don't want that, use Dicionaries.

Comment: You are welcome. **Pay attention to the warnings in the comments on your question. Although my answer fixes your code issue, it doesn't fix your design issue!**